# different between this.Page and (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler

Tags: asp.net

HI!

does anybody know about different between **this.Page** and **(Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler**?

i had a problem that **this.page** returned null, and someone wrote me that using the construct **"(Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler"** will be better.

1. what the different?
2. why and when **this.page** return null?

thanks!!

Shani

Answer (score 5):

`this.Page` will find a control's Page by searching it's parent hierarchy.

`HttypContext.Current.Handler` will find the page by looking at the current context (thread).

The first will be null even when the second is valid if the control hasn't been put into the page hierarchy yet.

Answer (score 1):

this.Page will only be available if the class (control) you are trying to access is already added in the Page's control hierarchy. If you have newly created child that is not added in hierarchy, it will not be able to determine it's page.