# Previous page title in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get previous page title in my asp.net application.

My attempt :

```
string previousPageTitle =  this.Page.PreviousPage.Title;
```

I am getting "NullReferenceException" as Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I do not want to use session or query string to get previous page title.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going to the page directly, thus resulting in `PreviousPage` being `null`.

[See Page.PreviousPage property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx)

> When you use the Transfer method or use cross-page posting to transfer
>   processing from one ASP.NET page to another, the originating page
>   contains request information that might be required for the
>   destination page. You can use the PreviousPage property to access that
>   information. If the current page is being rendered as a **result of a
>   direct request (not a transfer or cross-post from another page), the
>   PreviousPage property contains null**.

Comment: I am testing this by coming from another page and in my case current page is not rendered as a result of a direct request.

Comment: @Gaurav, are you using `Server.Transer` ?

Comment: If you are not using `Server.Transfer` to transfer control of the request from one page to the next, there will be no value in the `Page.PreviousPage` property. You need to use query string values or a similar alternative.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488967/different-between-this-page-and-pagehttpcontext-current-handler) SO question.

Is the reference to `this.Page` returning null? You could try accessing it through the `HttpContext` object:

```
((Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler).PreviousPage.Title
```